# SSRS BIDS Reporting Group By Header

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, business-intelligence, bids

[image]

Does anyone know how to make it so that when there are multiple records for a month (See image) there is only one line of data rather than splitting it into 4 boxes.

For example see June, I want this to have one box for RFC days and one box for Project days.

I have grouped by so far:

Row Groups - Service, MonthName

Column Groups - classification[image: Management Studio view - if any help]

Comment: This might be useful http://msftengprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2008!Grouping%20Sets%20Report

Comment: I'd run the raw SQL statement and see what comes back. If you have "multiple records for a month" in the SQL, you'll most likely also see them in the report.

Comment: Normally it should work. Check your row groups. Perhaps you have classification in one of your row groups

Comment: See second image - As you can see in the management studio view there are two lines for months which contain records for both 'RFC' and 'PROJECT' data, can there not be reported on in BIDS so that there is only one line for the month but the 'GROUP BY' on classification provides to colums for each classification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had to GROUP BY my MONTH field so I dragged this into the group by row groups, right clicked on it from here and in Group Properties added a group expression. [image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by using grouping and sum the values at the group level and hide the detail line.

However, the easiest thing to do is do it in SQL using nested queries, like so (you probably also want to order by the month number rather than name, as shown below):

```
SELECT Service, Month(DateField) AS MonthNumber, 
    MAX(DatePart(Month, DateField)) AS MonthName, 
    SUM(ProjectDays) AS ProjectDays, SUM(RFCDays) AS RFCDays
FROM (
    SELECT Service, DateField, Days AS ProjectDays, 0 AS RFCDays
    FROM Project
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Service, DateField, 0 AS ProjectDays, Days AS RFCDays
    FROM RFC
)
GROUP BY Service, Month(DateField)
ORDER BY Service, Month(DateField)
```